# How to add circular background on fontawesome 6?

Tags: css, font-awesome

How do I make my icon look like this [image: bed icon]

I'm using font awesome 6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon in a container.

```css
span {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EAF6F3;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

i {
  color: #96BBAA
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<span>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a circle. Also, you open a span and close a div

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icon {
  color: #60bd94;
}
.fa-circle{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<span class="fa-stack fa-2x icon">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bed fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```